# How to count dynamic xml nodes in XSLT?

Tags: xml, dynamic, count, nodes

I have a situation where I want to count the number of Tags returned based on a condition set on top of each node.

I have almost 20 Flags like shown in the below examples. We don't know how many of these flags will be true. If the Flag is TRUE, the custom text will be returned. I want to know the count of the flags returned. I tried many ways using Variables and I wasn't successful.

```
<!--CPSOR ALERT FLAG-->
<xsl:if test="Person/PersonInfo/CPSORFlag ='true'">                    
  <scope:PersonAlert>
    <!--PersonAlerts.PersonAlertText-->
    <scope:AlertText>                        
      <xsl:text>CONV PER/SOFF</xsl:text>
    </scope:AlertText>
  </scope:PersonAlert>
</xsl:if>
<!--CERTASADULT ALERT FLAG-->
<xsl:if test="Person/PersonInfo/CertAsAdultFlag ='true'">
   <scope:PersonAlert>
    <!--PersonAlerts.PersonAlertText-->
    <scope:AlertText>
      <xsl:text>CERT ADULT</xsl:text>
    </scope:AlertText>
  </scope:PersonAlert>
</xsl:if>
<!--DECEASED ALERT FLAG-->
<xsl:if test="Person/PersonInfo/DeceasedFlag ='true'">
  <scope:PersonAlert>
    <!--PersonAlerts.PersonAlertText-->
    <scope:AlertText>
      <xsl:text>DECEASED</xsl:text>
    </scope:AlertText>
  </scope:PersonAlert>
</xsl:if>
```

This is the Sample XML

[image]

Comment: ¿Is in Person/PersonInfo anything else alongside flags? Some knowledge of xml structure is required

Comment: Does my new solution work for you? I see you made a comment on michael kay's.

Comment: Hi James,
For now it hasn't worked yet. I don't know why it's happening like this. Is there a way, I can send you the XSL I am using by email ? so that you can look at the issue clearly. Since it's a very big file I can not put it here

Answer (score 1):

A classic example of a general problem: you want to compute two different results from the same input data. There are several approaches.

(a) Bite the bullet and process the input twice. This is the solytion james31rock has chosen.

(b) Same as (a) but try to identify expressions you are evaluating more than once, and put the results of these expressions in variables, to avoid repeated computation.

(c) Put the result of the first computation in a variable, and perform the second computation on the result of this variable.

I think I would be inclined to do something along the lines of (b). This is XSLT 2.0 - I only do XSLT 1.0 if you pay me a lot of money. Also, I'm assuming that the expressions like `Person/PersonInfo/CPSORFlag` each select a single node.

```
<xsl:variable name="flags" select="Person/PersonInfo/(CPSORFlag, CertAsAdultFlag, DeceasedFlag, ....)"/>

<xsl:variable name="count" select="count($flags[.='true'])"/>

<xsl:apply-templates select="$flags[. = 'true']"/>
```

then

```
<xsl:template match="Person/PersonInfo/*" priority="5">
   <scope:PersonAlert>
    <!--PersonAlerts.PersonAlertText-->
    <scope:AlertText>
      <xsl:next-match/>
    </scope:AlertText>
  </scope:PersonAlert>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CPSORFlag" priority="4">CONV PER/SOFF</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="CertAsAdultFlag" priority="4">CERT ADULT</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="DeceasedFlag" priority="4">DECEASED</xsl:template>

etc
```

Comment: Hi Michael.  Thanks for the reply. I am still unable to get the COUNT to work. 
Here is the code I tried after looking at your's and James examples:-


<xsl:variable name="AlertCount" select="count(//PersonInfo/ArrayOfPersonInfo[CPSORFlag[.='true'] or CertAsAdultFlag[.='true'] or DeceasedFlag[.='true'] or WantedFlag[.='true'] or ConditonalReleaseFlag[.='true'] or MissingFlag[.='true'] or ATLFlag[.='true']])"/>

Comment: You seem to be counting the number of ArrayOfPersonInfo elements that match a particular condition, but there is only one ArrayOfPersonInfo element in your input. Really, if you don't use the solution I gave you, you can't expect me to tell you why your solution doesn't work.

Comment: Sir, 
     I am extremely sorry for the misconception you had. I tried your solution and it was giving errors. The following line of code errors out all the time. Please let me know if I should change something

<xsl:variable name="flags" select="PersonInfo/ArrayOfPersonInfo/(CPSORFlag, CertAsAdultFlag, DeceasedFlag, ....)"/>

Comment: Perhaps you missed my remark that it needs an XSLT 2.0 processor. If not, telling me what the error is might help.

Comment: No the version is correct..
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
        xmlns:user="urn:user" extension-element-prefixes="msxsl"
        
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl user"
    version="2.0">

Comment: Saying version="2.0" in your stylesheet does not magically turn MSXML3 into an XSLT 2.0 processor.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your XML is like so:

```
<root>
  <Person>
    <PersonInfo>
      <CPSORFlag>true</CPSORFlag>
    </PersonInfo>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <PersonInfo>
      <ConditonalReleaseFlag>true</ConditonalReleaseFlag>
    </PersonInfo>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <PersonInfo>
      <MissingFlag>true</MissingFlag>
    </PersonInfo>
  </Person>
</root>
```

use the count() function

```
<NumberOfFlags>
<xsl:value-of select="count(//Person/PersonInfo[CPSORFlag[.='true'] or CPSORFlag[.='true']])"/>
</NumberOfFlags>
```

or

```
<NumberOfFlags>
<xsl:value-of select="count(//Person/PersonInfo[CPSORFlag='true' or CPSORFlag='true'])"/>
</NumberOfFlags>
```

Add all your different types of flags in the filter shown above

[CPSORFlag='true' or etc...]

Here is an proven example

[image: Number of flags]

**EDIT**

Given your newly pasted XML this templates should do the trick

**XML**

```
 <Person>
    <PersonInfo>
      <CPSORFlag>true</CPSORFlag>
       <MissingFlag>true</MissingFlag>
       <ConditonalReleaseFlag>true</ConditonalReleaseFlag>
    </PersonInfo>
  </Person>
```

**stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="java" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output media-type="text/xml" method="xml"/>
  <!-- Filters refdoc based on condition and  data  -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//PersonInfo"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PersonInfo">
    <NumberOfFlags>
         <xsl:value-of select="count(CPSORFlag[.='true']|MissingFlag[.='true']|ConditonalReleaseFlag[.='true'])"/>
     </NumberOfFlags>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Just need to add a new flag with the | symbol inside the count function

CPSORFlag[.='true'] | MissingFlag[.='true']

Comment: Hi James. Thanks a lot for the reply. Unfortunately I am still unable to get the count work.

 <xsl:variable name="AlertCount" select="count(//PersonInfo/ArrayOfPersonInfo[CPSORFlag[.='true'] or CertAsAdultFlag[.='true'] or DeceasedFlag[.='true'] or WantedFlag[.='true'] or ConditonalReleaseFlag[.='true'] or MissingFlag[.='true'] or ATLFlag[.='true']])"/>

I am getting the Count value=1 everytime.

Comment: @HarshavardhanJasthi, I edited my post. Please provide me with yor XML if what I posted is not what your XML looks like.

Comment: Hi James. I have attached the sample XML as an image. Please check it once and let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks again for your time and help.

Comment: @HarshavardhanJasthi I edited my post. The new stylesheet I provided should do the trick.